# SQL for public private records which depend on the project being selected

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, rights

I have a `term` DB. Each term may be private or public.
Terms are organized into `project`s.
There is a `user` table as well.

If I were to make an SQL to retrieve the data taking care of the public status and I know in advance whether I need to allow public it would look like this:

`SELECT * FROM term

JOIN project ON (project.id = term.id_project)

WHERE term.public = true` (could have been `WHERE public`, but clearer like this)

or

`WHERE (term.public = true OR term.public = false)` (could have been skipped completely, but clearer like this)

But, each user-project combination (`user_project_mm`) may be allowed or disallowed to see private projects. Trying to solve right away yields something like:

`SELECT * FROM term

JOIN project ON (project.id = term.id_project)

JOIN user_project_mm ON (user_project_mm.id_project = project.id)

WHERE user_project_mm.id_user = $currentUserID

[[IF user_project_mm.private THEN NOTHING ELSE AND term.public = true]]`

The code inside [[]] is clearly not SQL. This is some kind of SQL rewriting that is necessary here. The decision whether to append `AND term.public` or not depends on each particular result record field `user_project_mm.private`.

I don't want to post-process with PHP as this will ruin my pagination done with LIMIT and it's dirty anyway. Is there a clean SQL solution for this? Did I explain it clearly enough?

Comment: I want to select all records (including private) if it's allowed for $currentUser in the user_project_mm.private field.
I want to select ONLY public records for those projects which have false in user_project_mm.private field.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM term
JOIN project ON (project.id = term.id_project)
JOIN user_project_mm ON (user_project_mm.id_project = project.id)
WHERE user_project_mm.id_user = $currentUserID
AND (user_project_mm.private = true or term.public = true)
```

Comment: Seems to be it! I'll try and report my findings soon.

Answer (score 0):

@JackPDouglas had a very good idea and it's so straight simple! The end result looks like this:

`AND (user_project_mm.private OR (!user_project_mm.private AND term.public))`

Comment: I'd say that `X OR (NOT X AND Y)` is less clear than `X OR Y` (unless `X` can be `NULL` - can it?)